# Selecting Entity based on auto generated ID in google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created an entity with few attributes but without specifying any key  in which case an auto generated ID has been created in data-store.

```
     Entity en=new Entity("Job");
```

Now when I fetch such entities and try to store it in Java object, how can I get the auto generated ID (which I required to perform UPDATE operation later)?
I have tried the below ways but it does not return Identifier value.

```
     en.getProperty("__key__");
     en.getProperty("ID/Name");
     en.getProperty("Key");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
en.getProperty(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY)
```

mentioned in [Key Filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Key_filters) (not an obvious place to find it).

Another approach would be to try:

```
en.getKey().getId()
```

mentioned in [Entity JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity) and [Key JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key).

Comment: Thanks for replying but it still returning null  where as Data viewer shows the ID/Name values 2,3,4,5,etc

Comment: en.getKey().getId() is the right approach. If you call it after you saved an entity, you will never get a null.

Comment: Name is not auto generated. I suggest you remove it from your answer.