# Cannot retrieve entity with generated id in Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm using the Google Cloud Datastore in a very simple way, and I try to retrieve an entity by its id. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268257/selecting-entity-based-on-auto-generated-id-in-google-datastore) (it's in Java but seems to follow the same logic)

Def of my entity is here:

```
class Logs(ndb.Model):
    startDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    endDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    requestedDate = ndb.DateProperty()
    taskName = ndb.StringProperty()
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Then when I insert a new one I do

```
logs = Logs(startDate=datetime.utcnow(),
                taskName=taskName,
                requestedDate=requestedDate,
                status=u'IN_PROGRESS')

key = logs.put()
id = key.id() # I use this variable later
```

And when I want to retrieve it

```
logs = Logs.get_by_id(id)
```

But it never returns any entity...

What's wrong with this ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#retrieving_entities), you should be able to call get() directly from the Key object to retrieve the entity from Datastore:

```py
logs_entity = Logs(startDate=datetime.utcnow(),
                   taskName=taskName,
                   requestedDate=requestedDate,
                   status=u'IN_PROGRESS')

# Saves entity to Datastore and returns Key
entity_key = logs_entity.put()

# Retrieves entity from Datastore using the previous Key
result = entity_key.get()
```

**Edit:**

In the case where you need to pass around the key as a string to rebuild the Key object later you might try using the urlsafe() method, which allows embedding it in a URL:

```py
urlsafe_string = entity_key.urlsafe()

[...]

entity_key= ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe_string)
logs_entity = entity_key.get()
```

Comment: you're right. Forgot to mention, that between the time I put the entity in the datastore and the time I retrieve it, I need a stringified id (cause it's a param passed in a URL)